# Equivalent of 'this' pointer

Tags: vba, pointers, this

Is there an equivalent of `this` pointer in VBA so that I can pass it to another module?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not for a module, no. A module doesn't have an instance, so there is no instance variable to pass. All the methods are static. If you are within a class instance, however, you can use Me.

Answer (score 12):

Try "Me" for classes. Modules are global (like a static class) so have no instance concept.